# ruby JSON.pretty_generate() doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I'm trying to print JSON data in a view in a 'pretty' human readable format. I have a controller:

```
def show
  h = JSON.parse(RestClient.get("http://link_to_get_json"))
  @json = JSON.pretty_generate(h)
end
```

and a simple view:

```
= @json
```

But all I see, when I load the page, is the same JSON I've got, not formatted. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON.pretty_generate` inserts whitespace into the returned string.

If your'e dumping the string into an HTML document, all whitespace (such as newlines) is ignored, and rendered as a single space. In order to preserve whitespace, you need add a [`white-space: pre`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) CSS style, or wrap the content in a `<pre>` tag.

Comment: HTML embedded in the JSON is rendered in the <pre> block nonetheless. Would suggest: `@json = JSON.pretty_generate(CGI::escapeHTML(h))`

Comment: @dennis that’s not relevant to this question

Answer (score 0):

I think you were using `<p>`. wrap it up in `<pre>`.